# How do I get rid of scientific notation and covert to a floating number in Python?

Tags: python

I have been having trouble with Python in that I can't stop scientific notation and convert to a floating number. I have tried multiple methods, and none of them have done what I have wanted. Below is the code for a random number generator that continues on until it finds the number 7. At the end, it gives you statistics on the run. One gets added to x every time the loop goes through Thank you in advance.  Edit: The output is usually something like this:

Your computer just went through 279754 integers to find 7!

Your computer just took 4.462186096363586e-07 seconds to run!

Your computer took 1.5950392474686997e-12 seconds per integer!

What I have is:

```
x = 0
c = time.clock()
print("Your computer just went through " + str(x) + " integers to find 7!")
print("Your computer just took " + str(c) + " seconds to run!")
print("Your computer took " + str(c / x) + " seconds per integer!")
```

Comment: do you mean `%f` format?

Comment: What output do you see?  What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Which line of code is problematic? Can you reduce the problem to an example with one or two lines? The random number generation is of no interest.

Comment: What's wrong with scientific output? As far as it can be properly computed, your last example (1.59...e-12) will show the number more precisely than trying to output it in decimal notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.format()` instead. To not get the scientific notation (the `e-number` part), enter the specified length of the number.

```
import time

x = 210513
c = time.clock()
print("Your computer just went through {} integers to find 7!".format(x))
print("Your computer just took {0:.20f} seconds to run!".format(c))
print("Your computer took {0:.20f} seconds per integer!".format(c / x))
```

The `.20` part means that the float will be 20 numbers after the decimal point. Change the number to change the length, such as `.50` will have the float have 50 numbers after the decimal point and so on.

Computers run rather fast so the time can be surprisingly low at times.

Answer (score 1):

Use format and specify length after floating point.

```
print("Your computer just went through {} integers to find 7!".format(x))
print("Your computer just took {} seconds to run!".format(c))
print("Your computer took {0:.8f} seconds per integer!".format(c / x))
```

Your computer just went through 371 integers to find 7!
Your computer just took 0.026945 seconds to run!
Your computer took 0.00007263 seconds per integer!

Comment: Your computer just went through 210513 integers to find 7!
Your computer just took 4.462186096363586e-07 seconds to run!
Your computer took 0.00000000 seconds per integer!

Comment: Use this notation {0:.8f} in second line too.

Comment: Your computer seems to be pretty fast what about {0:.15f} in third line.

Comment: It keeps telling me that the time my computer is running is way lower than how long it actually took. Output: Your computer just took 0.00000045 seconds to run! It was more like 4.5 in real time.